# fallo de condicional de python

Tags: python

Primero antes que todo buenas tardes. Tengo un problema con el lenguaje de Python el cual, un condicional no me quiere funcionar en la consola, y no me suelta ningún tipo de error, entonce es porque se está mal interpretando algo, haciendo que los datos nunca coincidan con la condicional que se puse al `if`.

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que me multiplique y me divida el alto y el ancho dependiendo de lo que ponga el usuario .

Aqui está el código.

```
import random

ancho=int(input("introdusca el ancho del cuadro: "))
alto=int(input("introdusca el alto del cuadro: "))

almacenador_alto_ancho=alto*ancho

almacenador_alto_ancho_dividido=almacenador_alto_ancho/3

if type(almacenador_alto_ancho_dividido) == 'float':

    almacenador_alto_ancho_dividido_str=str(almacenador_alto_ancho_dividido)
    almacenador_alto_ancho_dividido_lista=int(almacenador_alto_ancho_dividido_str.split('.')[0])
    print(almacenador_alto_ancho_dividido_lista)
    print(type(almacenador_alto_ancho_dividido_lista))
```

Comment: `if type(almacenador_alto_ancho_dividido) == float:` Es `float` a secas (un tipo), no `"float"` (un string).

Comment: En vez de usar esa forma complicada para comprobar si una división no es exacta, usa el operador de módulo: `if(almacenador_alto_ancho % 3) > 0:`

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que evalúas el `if` comparándolo con una cadena de texto. Así debe de quedar:

```
if type(almacenador_alto_ancho_dividido) == float:
```

Quita las comillas al `float`.
Usa este código para probar:

```
if type(almacenador_alto_ancho_dividido) == float:
    print(almacenador_alto_ancho_dividido)
    print(type(almacenador_alto_ancho_dividido))
    print('Entro a la sentencia if')
```

Con las entradas `10` y `10` imprime:

```
33.333333333333336
<class 'float'>
Entro a la sentencia if
```

Answer (score 0):

Sólo imprime la variable almacenador_alto_ancho_dividido, todo el contenido del if está de más.

```
print(almacenador_alto_ancho_dividido)
```

Answer (score 0):

creo que depende de la versión de python que estés usando. Si estás usando python2, la división *entre enteros* siempre te va a dar un número entero (o una excepción, si divides por 0 y tal), por lo que **nunca** entraría al `if`.

Y por lo que estoy viendo en mi equipo, en python3 *siempre* vas a tener un número flotante, pero te lo pone de otra forma:

```
>>> type (8 / 2)
<class 'float'>
>>> type (8 / 2) == 'float'
False
>>> type (7 / 2) == 'float'
False
```

Así que en python3 **tampoco** entraría en el `if` (aunque por razones ligeramente diferentes), por lo menos como lo tienes en este momento.